# Why can't string literals be used in bash regular expression tests?

Tags: regex, string, bash, variables, literals

Why does the following bash script only print out `variable worked`?

```
#! /bin/bash

foo=baaz
regex='ba{2}z'

if [[ $foo =~ 'ba{2}z' ]]; then
    echo "literal worked"
fi

if [[ $foo =~ $regex ]]; then
    echo "variable worked"
fi
```

Is there something in the bash documentation that states the `=~` operator only works with variables, not literals? Does this limitation apply to any other operators?

Comment: In case it's relevant, I'm running `GNU bash, version 4.2.8(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)` on Natty Narwhal.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You don't need quotes for bash regex anymore:

```
#! /bin/bash

foo=baaz
regex='ba{2}z'

if [[ $foo =~ ba{2}z ]]; then
    echo "literal worked"
fi

if [[ $foo =~ $regex ]]; then
    echo "variable worked"
fi

# Should output literal worked, then variable worked
```

I can't remember which version changed this though.

Comment: Only the second option works if the string lliteral contains spaces

Answer (score 3):

Your code actually works as expected up until Bash 3.1.
But since Bash 3.2 the behavior of the pattern match operator has been changed. Quote from the latest [Bash Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Conditional-Constructs):

> “Any part of the pattern may be quoted to force it to be matched as a
>   string.“

And that is exactly what is happening here. You meant to use `{}` as meta characters, but since you quoted it Bash interprets them literally.
You have two options.:

1.You can turn on the 3.1 compatibility mode with `shopt -s compat31` like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
shopt -s compat31

foo=baaz
regex='ba{2}z'

if [[ $foo =~ 'ba{2}z' ]]; then
    echo "literal worked"
fi

if [[ $foo =~ $regex ]]; then
    echo "variable worked"
fi
```

2.You can port your code, by removing the quotations from the right hand side of the operator:

```
#!/bin/bash

foo=baaz
regex='ba{2}z'

if [[ $foo =~ ba{2}z ]]; then
    echo "literal worked"
fi

if [[ $foo =~ $regex ]]; then
    echo "variable worked"
fi
```