# Bash double square brackets regex match issue

Tags: bash

Consider the code below :

```
$ var1=bingo
$ var2=.ingo
$ if [[ "$var1" =~ $var2 ]]; then echo found; fi
found
$ if [[ $var1 =~ "$var2" ]]; then echo found; fi    # line 5
$ if [[ "$var1" =~ "$var2" ]]; then echo found; fi  # line 6
$ if [[ $var1 =~ $var2 ]]; then echo found; fi
found
```

Above is what I have done in bash shell.

Question is why didn't lines `5` and `6` print `found`?

I think I already know the answer, but I am looking for a simple easy to digest answer.

To conclude, when a variable(inside double quotes) is used at the right side of `=~` , will the double quotes just serve for variable expansion?

Comment: @fedorqui : Thanks for the edit, much better way to put it indeed

Comment: Any portion of the operand on the right of `=~` that is quoted is matched as a literal string.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why can't string literals be used in bash regular expression tests?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6665529/why-cant-string-literals-be-used-in-bash-regular-expression-tests)

Comment: @SeanBright : Actually the other question is a bit different from what I wished to ask. See the last part of the question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Assuming you are running Bash 3.2 or newer, the [bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Conditional-Constructs-1) (scroll down to the description of `[[…]]`) states:

> Any part of the pattern may be quoted to force the quoted portion to be matched as a string.

And further:

> If the pattern is stored in a shell variable, quoting the variable expansion forces the entire pattern to be matched as a string.

Before Bash 3.2, the example you provided would have worked as you expected.

Comment: Actually, I read this but it was a bit confusing. The variable expansion still takes place. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, but then the comparison fails as `bingo != .ingo`

Comment: Wonderful and thanks for the edit. Interestingly I missed the part you pointed out in the edit..

Comment: It may be useful to incorporate part of [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29732674/5209610), too. The key is that this is only true for Bash 3.2 and greater. In Bash 3.1, what you tried would have worked as you expected.

Comment: @VladislavMartin Done

Answer (score 3):

When you use double quotes, the expanded pattern is treated literally. So the `.` actually being treated literally, not as a Regex token i.e. any single character.

**Example:**

```
$ if [[ $var1 =~ "$var2" ]]; then echo found; fi
+ [[ bingo =~ \.ingo ]]

$ if [[ $var1 =~ $var2 ]]; then echo found; fi
+ [[ bingo =~ .ingo ]]
+ echo found
found
```